# Using Pull Push, columns are not interchanging their place in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 columns in a row: 8, 4 and 12. In mobile view, I want to interchange the position of 4 and 12
[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">Col 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12">Col 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code removes the responsiveness even in desktop view.

I need second column to be in third place and 3rd column to be in second place in mobile view

Comment: one way to do such a thing is with using media query but can you please share your current output image and desired output image?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Bootstrap 3? You can make use of reordering in Bootstrap 4:

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Push and Pull</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 order-sm-last">Col 3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 ">Col 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need a solution in bootstrap 3 only because the design is complete and it will be hard to recreate everything.